# Can one edit the sections in a Google Form after sending it?

Tags: google-forms

I sent out a Google Form with several conditional sections inside. After having some responses I realized that I made a mistake in setting the routing to one of the sections. The form skips the wrong Qs and continues with another Q than it was intended.
To date, this caused only a minor problem (less than 1% of the respondents), but the survey is still open, and the problem might be bigger if future respondents happen to be directed to this section based on their answers.

**Q:** Can I edit the logic of the sections for future respondents without losing the previous submissions and changing the link of the form? No further changes (adding/deleting questions) are needed, ONLY the setting of the sections should be modified at one point.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

**First of all make a copy of your form(a test form)**, link it to a new answer sheet and submit couple of test replies.
Following that, make the changes you want and submit again some replies.

**If you notice no changes** to your answer sheet, continue by making the same changes to the original form. Problem solved :)

**If you do notice differences** to the answer sheet, then **please follow these steps**.

***Important note**

If I were you, I would first make a note -by checking the already existing timestamps- of when the least activity is registered and take the following steps during a passive period.*

1. Change the logic of your sections
2. Unlink the answer sheet
3. Relink your form to the same answer sheet.

Following the above steps a new tab will be created in your answer sheet where new submissions will be recorded.
To have results from both tabs together, create a third tab where by using formulas you can import date both previous tabs.